# Using geoPosition.js with colobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, colorbox

I'm trying to create a colorbox link that ask the user for permission to detect his location, and if the user agree he gets a map with direction from his location.
Now I managed to make it work but not very well. In the first time when the user need to give permission the map loading perfectly, but in the second time when the permission already given the map not loading correctly.

my code:

```
function directionMap() {
  var position;
  jQuery('.direction-map').colorbox({
    maxWidth: '100%',
    maxHeight: '100%',
    opacity: 0.5,
    html: '<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>',
    onLoad:  function() {
      var success = function(pos) {
        var lat     = pos.coords.latitude,
            long    = pos.coords.longitude,
            coords  = {lat: lat, lng: long};

        var start = coords;
        var target = {lat: 31.273257, lng: 34.797528};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: start,
          scrollwheel: false,
          zoom: 7
        });

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          map: map
        });

        // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
        var request = {
          destination: target,
          origin: start,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            // Display the route on the map.
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });     
      }
      var error = function() {
        alert('Can\'t find your location');
      }
      if (geoPosition.init()) {
        geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {
          enableHighAccuracy:true,
          timeout: 1000
        });
      }
      return false;     
    },
  });
}
```

[My jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Liad91/3v0x7cq5/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem was that the map should load after the colorbox completed, but just if the permission for location was given. so I wrote it with "onclick" handler and load the colorbox in the success variable.
this is the code:

```
function directionMap() {
  document.getElementById('get_location').onclick = function() {
    var success = function(pos) {
      jQuery('.direction-map').colorbox({
        maxWidth: '100%',
        maxHeight: '100%',
        opacity: 0.5,
        html: '<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>',
        open: true,
        onComplete: function() {
          var lat     = pos.coords.latitude,
              long    = pos.coords.longitude,
              coords  = {lat: lat, lng: long};

          var start = coords;
          var target = {lat: 31.273257, lng: 34.797528};

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: start,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 7
          });

          var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
          });

          // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
          var request = {
            destination: target,
            origin: start,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };

          // Pass the directions request to the directions service.
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              // Display the route on the map.
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
          }); 
        }
      });

    }
    var error = function() {
      alert('Can\'t find your location');
    }

    if (geoPosition.init()) {
      geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {
        enableHighAccuracy:true,
        timeout: 1000
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```